# MonoTouch, UITableViewController, How to insert a row in a section?

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios, uitableview, xamarin

I designed a UITableViewController with static cells in XCode.
After click on a button I want to add a row in one of the sections with a result.

My code:

```
InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
    List<NSIndexPath> indexPaths = new List<NSIndexPath>();
    indexPaths.Add(NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 2));

    TableView.InsertRows(indexPaths.ToArray(), UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);
});
```

didn't work :-)
I get this error message: *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:1070

Answer (score 2):

Do you add data to your data source (IE a new row or section) after you insert the rows. You need to because inserting automatically does a myTable.reloadData, resulting in all the datasource methods being called again. If you explicitly told it to add a row at a specific index and it goes to reload and finds that index doesn't exists you get errors like this. Check cellForRow and numCellInSection

Comment: How can I add "my result" to the datasource? My TableView.DataSource is null.

Comment: Where do you get data from to populate your cells? Look up UITabeViewController documention but subclassing it should automatically provide you with the correct methods